# Error updating field conditionally in PostgreSQL-11

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, conditional-statements, expression, postgresql-11

Given the following query:

```
insert into shopify_app_shops as s
    (
        myshopify_name,
        hostname,
        user_status,
        offline_access_token,
        offline_access_token_updated_at,
        updated_at
    )
    values
    (
        %(myshopify_name)s,
        %(hostname)s,
        %(user_status)s,
        %(offline_access_token)s,
        now(),
        now()
    )
    on conflict (myshopify_name)
    do update
        set
            hostname=%(hostname)s,
            user_status=%(user_status)s,
            offline_access_token_updated_at =
            CASE
                WHEN offline_access_token == %(offline_access_token)s
                THEN offline_access_token_updated_at
                ELSE now()
            END,
            offline_access_token=%(offline_access_token)s,
            updated_at = now()
            returning myshopify_name
            ;
```

I get the error:

> Failed with: column reference "offline_access_token" is ambiguous LINE 28:       WHEN offline_access_token == NULL

However if I fully specify the field by prepending the table name like this:

```
WHEN shopify_app_shops.offline_access_token == %(offline_access_token)s
```

I instead get this error:

> Failed with: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "shopify_app_shops" LINE 28:       WHEN
>   shopify_app_shops.offline_access_token == NULL

At this point I am at loss what I should do!

The [documentation for postgresql-11 update statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) clearly states that expression used for set value can contain references to the other fields to get access to the old values:

> expression
>
> An expression to assign to the column. The expression can use the old values of this and other columns in the table.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the table alias

```
WHEN s.offline_access_token ...
```

A table name is not visible when an alias was used. Not related, you should probably use [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) instead of `==`.